# How to measure noise or sound and displays in dB(A) in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, meter

I want to measure sound in dB(A) in iPhone.

How can I do it?

Is there any example or tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AVAudioPlayer, you can use this method

```
AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer = ...
[avPlayer play...];
[avPlayer averagePowerForChannel:0];
[avPlayer averagePowerForChannel:1];
```

From Apple's doc

> - (float)averagePowerForChannel:(NSUInteger)channelNumber
>
> Description
> Returns the average power for a given channel, in decibels, for the sound being played.

Comment: Yes, but "average power ... in decibels" is surely giving you the [power in dB relative to full scale (dBFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS) not [dBA(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-weighting). I think you need a proper, calibrated SPL meter to get a dBA measurement.

Comment: This is dBFS and not DB(A).