# iOS get sound loudness

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I am developing a iPhone application that needs realtime sound processing. What i would like to archive is to get the sound loudness (from the microphone), compare it with a threshold and do some logic based on the loudness level. Is there any library in iOS that would enable me to do this? Does iOS have any built in function that would give me the current sound loudness level?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "loudness"? There's sound intensity, which is volume and trivial to measure, but loudness is entirely different: loudness is the human perception of volume. There are also various measures of loudness which approximate human perception, including VU, dBA, etc.

Comment: checkout the Speak Here sample project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183599/how-to-measures-noise-or-sound-and-displays-in-dba-in-iphone) looks like a good place to start (it's close enough to be a dupe, maybe, but I figured I'd answer anyway).